# SUM Values Treat as POS or NEG based on Text value from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm using SQL Server Managment Studio. I'm trying to SUM "Amount" column using CASE condition that if my DCIP column value = D then Treat "Amount" as Positive Integer ELSE if DCIP value = C then Treat "Amount" as a Negative Integer. End as Net Amount

```
DCIP    Amount  Name
-----------------------
C   100 Jack
C   100 Jack
D   300 Freddie
D   50  Jack
D   25  Freddie
C   100 Freddie
```

I'm grouping by Name, which should return the below results:

```
Net Amount Name
---------------
-150       Jack
225.       Freddie
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT NAME,
       Net_Amount = Sum(CASE DCIP WHEN 'D' THEN Amount ELSE -Amount END) 
FROM   table
GROUP  BY NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to:

```
select
Amount *
CASE DCIP
    WHEN 'D' THEN 1 
    ELSE -1
END 
from table
```

and then take a sum of such expresion and group by user

```
select
sum(Amount *
CASE DCIP
    WHEN 'D' THEN 1 
    ELSE -1
END)
from table
group by name
```

Comment: Yes, conditional aggregation. You could fix your typo, 'I thin you'

Comment: This worked fine. I tweaked it a little bit though. I ended up using:  SELECT SUM(CASE Table.Amount WHEN 'D' then Table.Amount *1 ELSE Table.Amount *-1 END AS Net_Amount GROUP BY Name